# Problemas con localhost

Tags: javascript, mysql, mongodb

Estoy trabajando en un nuevo proyecto con BDD en `MongoDB` y en `MySql`. Al hacer el usuario todo iba bien pero al hacer un mere con una rama de un compañero y volver a clonarla, cuando intento hacer el login me tira un error y me desconecta. No entiendo el por que si funcionaba antes, espero podáis ayudarme

```js
MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/javi/Desktop/Introduccion_bootcamp/Backend/ProyectoFullBack/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:306:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        _hostAddress: HostAddress { isIPv6: false, host: 'localhost', port: 27017 },
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 19290292,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (/Users/javi/Desktop/Introduccion_bootcamp/Backend/ProyectoFullBack/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:382:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/javi/Desktop/Introduccion_bootcamp/Backend/ProyectoFullBack/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:302:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:652:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:537:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
        }
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

Comment: Javier, tu código estaba funcionando y dejó de funcionar? Tu pregunta dice que tienes problemas en `localhost`, eso significa que cuando lo subes a un servidor remoto funciona pero en `localhost` no funciona? Si sos tan amable, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/541647/edit) tu pregunta y aclara o muestra el el código para entender mejor el problema. Gracias!

Comment: Eso me suena a mi que si otra persona a realizado un commit te ha machacado la configuración que tenias

Comment: @JordiTurell si, esa es la cosa, ya me he dado cuenta que han destrozado lo que tenia.....

Comment: Sin saber la diferencia en el código es casi imposible determinar cuál es el problema en cuestión.